# How do I start over in Git?

Tags: git

I really did a number on my Git installation. I accidentally added an origin with incorrect upperlowercase, and I cant figure out how to remove the "Wrongly named" version from git's procedures. Along the way, I tried to modify the core.ignorecase in git/config and now git won't do anything (it just gives me: fatal: bad config value for 'core.ignorecase' in .git/config)

Anyways, I just want to start the f over. I located my Git being here:     /usr/bin/git
, but the rm command doesnt seem to have any effect.

1. way to uninstall everything git?
2. way to then reinstall?

Thank you

Comment: Got it to work the second time around. Not being able to fix the capitals after a screw up seems like a major wtf... But by being careful the second time around it worked fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `rm` your `~/.gitconfig` file and you should be fine.

How to reinstall git depends on how you installed it. In case of a Debian based system this should work:

```
apt-get install --reinstall git
```

Comment: @StrikePricer Could you explain further (by editing the question) what exactly the issue is? I don't understand what was wrong with the case?

Comment: the issue was that I had accidentally typed in a lower case version of my github link, and so my local git thought that was okay, but then the capitalization really DID matter when I went to push, as the caps need to be exact. This same "step 1 caps dont matter" "in step 2 they do" made it impossible to fix, as I couldnt add the correct caps version without git thinking that it already knew about it. essentially I had to start over. it works fine now though. I apologize for any confusion, and I actually thought asking how to start over was BETTER for the community (re: whoever downvoted).